# Creating a dynamic street panorama in info window (Google Maps Javascript API)

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-street-view

I am trying to create a panorama street view to a google marker info window  that is currently selected. So far, I have the info window that appearing with the location title. However, I wish to show the panorama right below it. I am getting errors such as 'cannot read properties such as style of undefined'.

Below is the functionality I have so far:

```
var map;
var markers = [];

var ViewModel = function() {


  var self = this;

  //Pushes the array of location titles onto the DOM
  self.locationsArray = ko.observableArray(locations);

  //Zooms to location on the map of currently clicked location
  //Place refers to the current location selected in the DOM
  //Example place = locations[current # in array]
  self.goToLocation = function(place,status) {
    console.log('Lat='+place.location.lat+', Lng='+place.location.lng);
    var coordinates = [place.location.lat,place.location.lng];
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[0],coordinates[1]);
    map.panTo(latlng);
    map.setZoom(16);
  };

  self.zoomIn = function() {
    map.setZoom(map.zoom+1)
    if(map.zoom >= 20) {
      alert('Whataya doin, lookin for ants?');
      map.setZoom(map.zoom-6);
    }
  };

  self.zoomOut = function() {
    map.setZoom(map.zoom-1)
    if(map.zoom <= 10) {
      alert('Ay fugetaboutit.. you\'re way atta Brooklyn! Zoom in to see the gabagool.')
      map.setZoom(map.zoom+4);
    }
  };

  // http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-1-passing-a-current-item-as-a-parameter-to-your-handler-function
  // click binding's callback method
  // write a string to the console (first goal)

  // filter funcionality


};

function initMap() {

  var self=this;

    var styles = [
      {
        featureType: 'water',
        stylers: [
          {color: '#000000'}
        ]
      },{
        featureType: 'administrative',
        elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
        stylers: [
          {color: '#ffffff'},
          {weight: 6}
        ]
      }];
    //Below stores the map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
      //Below sets the initial location of the map on the screen
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6251388,-74.0282899),
      //{lat: 40.6301388,lng:-74.0282899},
      //Below sets the level of zoom (1 = farthest away possible)
      zoom: 14,
      styles: styles
    });

    //Storing the infoWindow constructor to recall dynamically
    //for each location array
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    //var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama();
      //map.setStreetView(panorama);

    //For every location, create a marker(with specified properties)
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position : new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].location),
        map : map,
        title : locations[i].title,
        animation : google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon : 'forkknife.png'
      });

      //Attach a click event to each marker displaying the infoWindow
      //It will zoom to level 16, set the content to the appropriate location
      //then open it
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
          return function() {
            map.setZoom(16);
            infoWindow.setContent(locations[i].title+'<br>'/*+Pano to go here*/);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          }
        })(marker, i));
    }

    // create markers objects, for example, here
    // viewModel.locations()[index].marker = marker
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Below is the data:

```
var locations = [
  {
    title: 'Nino\'s Pizza',
    location: {
      lat: 40.620057,
      lng: -74.032894
    }
  },
  {
    title: 'Shore Road Bike Path',
    location: {
      lat: 40.623089,
      lng: -74.040596
    }
  },
  {
    title: 'Paneantico Bakery',
    location: {
      lat: 40.619418,
      lng: -74.0322818
    }
  }]
```

And lastly the View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--All code written by Thomas Grimes with the help of Udacity.com-->
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Map Project - Thomas Grimes</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: 'Asap Condensed', sans-serif; background-color:black;">
    <div class='container'>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" id="topBar" style="text-align:center;margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;border-bottom:solid white 1px;padding:5px">
          <span style="color:white;">Where to eat in . . .
            <span style="font-size: 300%">
               Bay Ridge
             </span>
           </span>
        </div>
        <hr>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-3' style="text-align:center;background-color:#1D2120;border: solid white 2px;" id="sideBar">
          <span>
            <br>
            <button type="button" style="background-color:black;color:white;width:50px;" data-bind="click:zoomIn">+</button>
            <button type="button" style="background-color:black;color:white;width:50px;" data-bind="click:zoomOut">-</button>
          </span>
          <ul style="padding:0;" data-bind="foreach:locationsArray">
            <li class="sideBarElements">
              <span id="place" data-bind="text:title,click:$parent.goToLocation"></span>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <img src="bridge.png">
          <input type="text" id="title">
          <input type="text" id="lat">
          <input type="text" id="lng">
          <button type="button" name="button">Add location</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <script src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
    <script src="model.js"></script>
    <script src="viewModel.js"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,geometry&key=AIzaSyDnuPkFW6XLlwH-L6RXzlpEMyLsQFZghXE&v=3&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are syntax errors in the posted code.  Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google maps adding streetview to each infowindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227255/google-maps-adding-streetview-to-each-infowindow)

Comment: Mistake should be fixed now. I only added a snippet and not the full functionality. It should be fine now.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_StreetViewInInfoWindowB.html)?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that exhibits the issue.  Your posted code is not minimal (where is `ko` defined?)

Comment: @geocodezip Yes! That is exactly what I am trying to do. PS apologies for the code troubles.

Comment: @geocodezip I am using the knockout JS framework and the MVVM format for data/view. I did post the entire code I have with exception to the styles which I don't believe is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the marker click handler, you need to create some DOM elements on you own, that you pass to the infoWindow content slot, **instead of html**.

By doing so, you'll be able to pass the reference of a div element to the google.maps.StreetViewPanorama constructor,

Take the example there and replace `document.getElementById('pano')` by some div element created in your click handler and also passed to infoWindow.content among other elements.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview